# jQuery UI datepicker и опция changeMonth

Tags: jquery, javascript

Суть в чем: если я создаю datepicker и ставлю ему numberOfMonths больше одного (например 2) и ставлю changeMonth или changeYear в true, то selectbox'ы генерируются только над первым месяцем (как [здесь](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range)). Как добиться генерации selectbox'ов над всем месяцами?

Comment: Ну нифига се сколько тут непонятных слов! :(-) Прям не за что ухватиться чтобы понять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В коде datepicker'а [зашито](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js#L1544): select'ы для месяца и года добавляются только для первого.

1. Тупо самому заменять span'ы с месяцем и годом на свои селекты со своими же обработчиками.
2. Плохой вариант, но в качестве проверки получится ли вообще стандартными возможностями обойтись подойдет. Поменять в коде (см. ссылку выше) `row > 0 || col > 0` на `true`. проверить если работает как хочется, то см. третий вариант.
3. Можно попробовать вызвать самостоятельно `$.datepicker._generateMonthYearHeader` (параметр отвечающий за селекты - secondary) с соответствующими параметрами для последующих месяцев после показа календарей (пока не ткнешь в input в dom'е необходимых элементов не будет). дальше получив html, заменить на него код в соответствующих `.ui-datepicker-group-middle` и `.ui-datepicker-group-last`. Потом вызвать дополнительно `$.datepicker._attachHandlers`. Ну и при листании тоже нужно подменять html. В общем не все так просто.

А вообще не очевидный интерфейс получится, ну решение (если есть) не простое тоже, да.

Comment: учитывая, что первый селект меняет значения всех месяцев, то зачем вообще нужно 3 селекта...не понимаю

Comment: @Spectre иногда с заказчиками проще не спорить а сделать как просят, а потом переделать назад, получив допбабло за переработку.

Comment: спасибо большое, второй вариант спас :)